# control-flowed variable in Bash

Tags: bash, scripting, variable, stability

The web-application document-root for Debian-Apache is typically `/var/www/html/` but for Arch-Apache it's typically `/srv/http/`.

I wrote a distro-agnostic LAMP-establishment script and I need it to test what is the distro-oriented document-root dir (based on the dir's existence) and the one that is `true` is the one I would continue to work with till the end of the script.

I usually do `drt="/var/www/html"` but I need to have the variable control flowed like in this pseudocode:

```
drt="/var/www/html XOR /srv/http"
```

Of course, only one of the two or more options is true, and that should base the XOR conditioning.

Is there a way to do so in Bash?

Comment: The dir's existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need it to test what is the distro-oriented document-root dir (based on the dir's existence)

From those two options, you could use `[ -d dir ]` to see if they exist:

```
if [ -d /var/www/html ]; then
    drt=/var/www/html;
elif [ -d /srv/http ]; then
    drt=/srv/http
else
    echo "No HTTP server root directory found"
    exit 1
fi
```

or, with a loop:

```
drt=
for d in /var/www/html /srv/http; do
    if [ -d "$d" ]; then
        drt=$d;
        break 
    fi
done
if [ -z "$drt" ]; then
    echo "No HTTP server root directory found"
    exit 1
fi
```

Of course, all of this assumes that they're actually using the distro's default document root, which might not be the case. It might not be a bad idea to give the user a chance to verify that the directory found by the script is the correct one.